# Clojure: "transpose" efficiently a medium sized list of maps

Tags: performance, list, clojure, maps, storage

I need a very fast and efficient way to "transpose" a list of maps in clojure.

Let's say I have:

```
(def monthly-sales [{:month 1 :pc "A" :sales 100} 
 {:month 2 :pc "B" :sales 200} ... {:month 12 :pc "Z" :sales 100}])
```

I need to have something like:

```
 |PC|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|
 |A|100||||||||||||
 |Etc.|
```

I answer the question below:

```
 (let [grouped (group-by (apply juxt [:month]) monthly-sales)]
       (apply str (interpose "\n" 
     (for [k (distinct (map :pc rows))] 
           (str "|" k "|" (clojure.string/join "|" 
         (for [n (range 1 13)]
               (get (first (filter #(= (:pc %) k) (get grouped [n]))) :sale))))))))))))
```

Basically I grouped all the values by month (group-by, notice that it can be keyed on more than 1 key thanks to "apply juxt"), this is the key for the column. Done that, I extrapolate the unique values of pc, this would be the key for the row. Rest should be self explanatory.

**Do you think this is clear clojurian design? Can it be more efficient and clear?**

Useful Links:
http://pramode.net/clojure/2010/06/01/lazy-sequences-in-clojure/

Answer (score 3):

Idiomatic clojure libraries (like clojure.java.jdbc) will provide these long lists as lazy seqs. That means you just need enough memory to contain a single row plus the usual overhead for loading clojure and the libraries - provided you get the data from a file or database and write it out to a stream/db/whatever and not keep it all in memory.

As for the transform you're asking for, given a seq of rows (maps) called result-set, something like:

```
(interpose "\n"
  (map (fn [row]
    (clojure.string/join "|" (map row [:consumer :product ...]))
    result-set)))
```

Will give you a lazy seq that you can just dump to a file to produce something like the | separated data you want.

Addendum: as for "fast" - unless your storage setup is unusual, this is likely to significantly faster than your storage I/O - and it's straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in this post suggests what end goal you want to achieve by processing this dataset. At least, I don't think the main idea could be putting 1GB of data into a HTML table. As such, no information can be given how this is best achieved. Just rearranging the same data isn't going to give any meaningful results, or change the memory or access requirements for the operations you want to do afterwards.

To begin with, what you show as 'base' data looks like it could be the results from a joined query on at least three relational tables (if properly normalized). It might be much more efficient to get information directly from these tables by SQL, already cutting down the amount of information, filtering or sorting before processing within Clojure itself.

If it's not, properly normalizing the data and storing it in a database might be an option, but all depends on what you want to do with the data in the end.